# Mongodb C driver with my program

Tags: c, mongodb

I had dl the Mongodb-c-driver from github.com, and compile it without problem, however, while I try to compile my C program, problem occurs:

```
testmongo.c:(.text+0x20): undefined reference to 'mongo_client'
testmongo.c:(.text+0x80): undefined reference to 'mongo_destroy'
```

I have link the mongodb library in ldconfig, however, this situation don't change...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mongo.h>

int main() {
  mongo conn[1];
  int status = mongo_client( conn, "127.0.0.1", 27017 );

  if( status != MONGO_OK ) {
      switch ( conn->err ) {
        case MONGO_CONN_NO_SOCKET:  printf( "no socket\n" ); return 1;
        case MONGO_CONN_FAIL:       printf( "connection failed\n" ); return 1;
        case MONGO_CONN_NOT_MASTER: printf( "not master\n" ); return 1;
      }
  }

  mongo_destroy( conn );

  return 0;
}
```

Could anyone Help?
Thank you very much !!!

Comment: What command are you using to compile it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I should submit this as an answer until more information is given. On a hunch, you might be missing `-lmongoclient` from your gcc command.

```
gcc -o myprog -lmongoclient source.c
```

Comment: Thank you v much for you help!!!
It work when I compile with:

    gcc -o myprog -lmongoc mysource.c

However, any way that I could only run

    gcc -o myprog mysource.c

to get the same result ??

Thanks !!

Comment: No you will need to tell gcc which libraries to include. You can use a Makefile to simplify the process: http://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/