# i get error "undefined reference to `mongo_client'" in compiling c use mongodb c driver

Tags: c, linux, mongodb

here is  demo code,i use it to test if everything is ok

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mongo.h>

int main()
{
   mongo conn[1];
   int status = mongo_client( conn, "127.0.0.1", 27017 );

   if( status != MONGO_OK ) {
      switch ( conn->err ) {
         case MONGO_CONN_NO_SOCKET:
             printf( "no socket\n" );
             return 1;
         case MONGO_CONN_FAIL:
             printf( "connection failed\n" );
             return 1;
         case MONGO_CONN_NOT_MASTER:
             printf( "not master\n" );
             return 1;
      }
   }
   printf( "connection done\n");

   mongo_destroy( conn );

   return 0;
}
```

here is compiling error information,i do not know why,it can not find mongo driver?

```
# cc --std=c99 demo.c -o demo
/tmp/ccucuugp.o: In function `main':
demo.c:(.text+0x2e): undefined reference to `mongo_client'
demo.c:(.text+0xc2): undefined reference to `mongo_destroy'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

any one can help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mongodb C driver with my program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15939976/mongodb-c-driver-with-my-program) - please paste your error message in google before posting here, you'll save yourself the trouble of posting a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out,by do this procedure

```
# echo '/usr/local/lib/' > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/mongoc.conf
# ldconfig
# gcc -lmongoc --std=c99 demo.c -o demo
```